# milliseconds to full date returns wrong day in my time zone

Tags: swift, date, time, formatter

I have developed an app which must show the current date and time not reading from device but from a http-get service

I read a long integer from server and I should converted to current year month day and time

I'm using this method but returns a wrong day and time.

```
func setDay(day:Double) {


    let formatter = DateFormatter()
    formatter.calendar = Calendar(identifier: .persian)
    formatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "fa_IR")
   var date = Date(timeIntervalSince1970: (day / 1000.0))
    // day
    formatter.dateFormat = "dd"


    //time=formatter.string(from: date)

    self.day = formatter.string(from: date)
    print(self.day) //wrong day
}
```

for example the long integer is : 1532928652552.0

and the day of this month in my country is 11 but returns 8

Comment: Can you add a test value, along with current output and expected output?

Comment: tanks I edited my first post

Comment: Is it 1532927876478.0 on epoch time?!

Comment: it is millisecond. actually it is java long

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
func convertEpochToStringDate(epoch: Int) -> String {
    let dbl = TimeInterval(epoch)
    let date = Date(timeIntervalSince1970: dbl)

    let formatter = DateFormatter()
    formatter.calendar = Calendar(identifier: .persian)
    formatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "fa_IR")
    formatter.dateFormat = "dd"
    formatter.timeZone = TimeZone(identifier: "IRST")

    return formater.string(from: date)
}
```

Let's test it:

```
let time = convertEpochToStringDate(epoch: 1532928652552 / 1000)
print(time)
```

Out put: `۰۸`

Comment: return 15 MORDAD today is 11. do you think my system is the problem?? I have change my timezone in my system

Comment: Vahid it must be 11 not 08. today is 11 Of MORDAD

Comment: @M0TRIX, this number: 1532928652 is for 8 Mordad. Check it here: https://www.epochconverter.com/. So you're passing wrong epoch time.

Comment: I just added time zone Identifier for Iran Time too.

Comment: @M0TRIX, note that 1532928652552 / 1000 is not "today", but rather July 30th in the gregorian calendar (ie. 3 days ago). It's probably no coincidence that 8 and 11 are also 3 apart.

Comment: my mistake Vahid.plus 1 for you

Comment: @M0TRIX, cool, notice: If you want to be same time in Iran time in different times in world, don't forget to set timeZone to `IRST` ;-)

Comment: Vahid will you cheek my new thread. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51653088/string-to-date-in-my-timezone-make-wrong-date