# string to date in my timeZone make wrong date

Tags: swift, time, nsdateformatter, formatter

I'm trying to convert String to date in my country time zone but the result is not as formatted I did

```
   let dbl = TimeInterval(longDate)

    let date = Date(timeIntervalSince1970: dbl / 1000)

    let formatter = DateFormatter()
    print(longDate)

    formatter.calendar = Calendar(identifier: .persian)
    formatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "fa_IR")
    formatter.timeZone = TimeZone(identifier: "IRST")

    formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
  let a = formatter.string(from: date)
 resultDate = dateFormatter.date(from: a)
 print(reslutDate,a) //2018-08-02 11:56:28 +0000 incorrect time 1397-05-11 15:56:28 correct time
```

in print line date is correct but the time is incorrect. I need this time to my Timepicker

update :

I have listener for time when I change the time set the value on textField

like below :

```
   self.timePickerFrom.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.dateChangedFrom(_:)), for: .valueChanged).  // the listener
```

and this is what I do for changing value :

```
let date = self.timePickerFrom.date
    print(date)
    let components = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.hour, .minute], from: date)
    let hour = components.hour!
    let minute = components.minute!

        self.timeOfloadingLable.text = "\(hour):\(minute)"
```

but the problem is when I change minute goes 30Min forward

Comment: I see.i have set dateFormatter seems not working

Comment: check timeIntervalSince1970 API its give UTC time [Returns a `Date` initialized relative to 00:00:00 UTC on 1 January 1970 by a given number of seconds]

Comment: you have to add or subtract the amount of time to get your local zone time wrt UTC time zone, and comment this code -> formatter.timeZone = TimeZone(identifier: "IRST")

Comment: they are all correct. when I convert string to date (before last line) makes problem

Comment: Your are trying to show an epoch time in Iran time on DateTime Picker?

Comment: yes. just cheek my first post. last line(print line)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your are doing it in wrong way, You should set format on date picker not the `date` of date picker.

Look at this code:

```
@IBOutlet weak var epoch: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var dateTimePicker: UIDatePicker!

@IBAction func presentDate(_ sender: UIButton) {
    guard let text = epoch.text else {return}
    guard let epoch = Double(text) else {return}
    guard let date = convertDate(epoch: epoch) else {return}

    dateTimePicker.date = date
    dateTimePicker.timeZone = TimeZone(identifier: "IRST")
    dateTimePicker.locale = Locale(identifier: "fa_IR")
    dateTimePicker.calendar = Calendar(identifier: Calendar.Identifier.persian)
}

private func convertDate(epoch: Double) -> Date? {
    let date = Date(timeIntervalSince1970: epoch)
    return date
}
```

[image: sample]

Is it what you mean?

I just uploaded a sample project, you can check it here: [sample project](https://github.com/vahids/Persian-date-time-picker)

Comment: @M0TRIX Please do not mess two question in one topic. I can't answer your new question in this topic. change back your edit and ask new question.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51655707/action-listener-for-timepicker