# action listener for timePicker

Tags: swift, time, listener, nsdateformatter

I have a timePicker which I have declared a listener if user change the time string sets on textFiled.

```
func timeFromAction(){

    DispatchQueue.main.async {

        self.timePickerFrom.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerMode.time
        //self.timePickerFrom.minimumDate = self.minDate
        print(self.minDate)
        self.timePickerFrom.date = self.minDate // current date I have achieve from millisecond to date

        self.timePickerFrom.locale = Locale(identifier: "fa_IR")
        self.timePickerFrom.calendar = Calendar(identifier: Calendar.Identifier.persian)

        self.timePickerFrom.timeZone = TimeZone(abbreviation: "IRST")

        self.timePickerFrom.frame=CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 288, height: 83)

        self.timeOfLoading.addSubview(self.timePickerFrom)

        self.timePickerFrom.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.dateChangedFrom(_:)), for: .valueChanged)

    }
}
```

this is the listener function :

```
func dateChangedFrom(_ sender: Any) {

    let date = self.timePickerFrom.date
    print(date)
    let components = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.hour, .minute], from: date)
    let hour = components.hour!
    let minute = components.minute!
    self.timeOfloadingLable.text = "\(hour):\(minute)"

}
```

so the problem is when I change the time no matter hour or minute.time goes 1 hour forward.

in listener function I'm getting date from timePicker which when I print it it is wrong although I have set a correct date on it

update :

```
self.minDate=self.crrnt.getComperehensiveDate()
```

and this is the function I use for it :

```
func setComperehensiveDate(longDate:Double){

        let dbl = TimeInterval(longDate)

        let date = Date(timeIntervalSince1970: dbl / 1000)


        resultDate = date

    }

 func getComperehensiveDate()->Date{

        print("bbbbbb",resultDate!)
        return resultDate!
    }
```

when time is 11:59 shows me 11:33 like below

[image]

cheek this video :  [link](http://uploadkon.ir/5vg)

Comment: are you sure about the `minDate` is currect?! please share `minDate`

Answer (score 0):

I just checked your code, It's working well, Please make sure your `longDate` is correct.

You're passing wrong epoch time. Check your epoch time here: https://www.epochconverter.com/

Comment: cheek my first post

Comment: longDate is correct I've cheeked and I set it on timePicker show the correct time. my problem shows up when I change the time

Comment: I checked all of your code in my sample project, It's working well for me. Could you share your code?

Comment: Vahid this is all my code. I edited my first post. I think time zone not effecting on timePicker

Comment: Did you check `dbl` value on www.epochconverter.com ?

Comment: yes.for example right now I',m typing this my dbl value is :1533368778635.0

Comment: It should return Saturday, Mordad 12, 2018 11:16:18 AM in Iran Time

Comment: listener is working wrongly when I change hour and min. the hour show 1 hour later

Comment: I check again your code. It's working for me. call this method: `setComperehensiveDate(longDate: 1533368779000)` and after that change picker. The picker and label should display same time.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/177405/discussion-between-vahid-and-m0trix).

Comment: I recored a clip linked in chat room